# i create an app its work test mode but release mode crashes when tapping on TextFormField in release mode on Android 11

Tags: android, flutter, dart

textfield code is :

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 130,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
      child: TextField(
             enabled: !isProgress,
             controller: userNumberController,
             keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
                   border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                   hintText: "01XXXXXXXX",
             ),
      ),
),
```

show this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25768): Process: com.m360.ontheway_queen, PID: 25768
E/AndroidRuntime(25768): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.view.WindowInsets android.view.WindowInsetsAnimation$Callback.onProgress(android.view.WindowInsets, java.util.List)"
E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress(View.java:11384)
E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress(ViewGroup.java:7433)
E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress(ViewGroup.java:7439)
E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress(ViewGroup.java:7439)
E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress(ViewGroup.java:7439)
E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress(ViewGroup.java:7439)
E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewRootInsetsControllerHost.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress(ViewRootInsetsControllerHost.java:106)**strong text**
```